# Selection: Check if DOM element can be wrapped?

Tags: javascript, dom, range

I want to wrap a `node` with e.g. `<span my-attribute="test">`.

The user selects a `node` and I would wrap it with [Range.surroundContents()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents)

My challenge now is to wrap ONLY `nodes` which have one level, e.g. this should be wrappable

```
<div><span>wrappable</span></span>
```

while this selection won't be wrappable

```
<div><span>wrappable</span></span>
<p>Paragraph in selection</p>
```

or this neither

```
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
```

The working example should finally look like

```
<span my-attribute="test">
  <div><span>wrappable</span></span>
</span>
```

I didn't find a matching method on the Range. I found [Range.commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer). But here I have no clue what to compare with what. Any hints?

Comment: How are you querying the elements? I supposed all of them have parent nodes right? Do you simply want to wrap those elements wherein they don't have siblings? or do you want to wrap those elements (which are parent nodes), that doesn't have more than one child node?

Comment: I get the nodes from an editor (`tiny`). Perhaps the idea with siblings is a good approach. I'll update the question as well about how it should look like.